# iPad extend to monitor

Tags: ipad, display

I have the following iPad mtxn2b/a with 16.2 installed.

When I plug in a monitor, it dupliacates the screen but I can't find anywhere in the options to extend onto the monitor to fill the entire screen.

Is this supported by my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your iPad as a second display for your Mac.  It’s called [Sidecar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380).

You cannot, however, extend your iOS/iPadOS Desktop to a second screen with your particular iPad.  You can mirror it or transmit it via AirPlay. The iPad simply doesn’t have the GPU horsepower to drive two separate displays like you’re accustomed to on a desktop.

#### [Stage Manager](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/move-resize-and-organize-windows-ipad1240f36f/16.0/ipados/16.0#iPad515fef4b)

Stage Manger is a feature available on selected iPad Pro and iPad Air models that *does* allow you to extend your screen. As of this post, there are only [three supported models](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/aside/ipad3de50547/16.0/ipados/16.0):

- iPad Air 5th Generation
- iPad Pro 11” (3rd Gen. or later)
- iPad Pro 12.9” (5th Gen. or later)

(IMO), this is a productivity boosting feature, but I’ve found that no matter how I slice it, a moderately sized MacBook Air M1/M2 is far more efficient when working with resource intensive apps like Excel or coding and an iPad on the lower end covers my daily needs.  Of course, YMMV.

Comment: What is this referring to then? https://www.zdnet.com/article/ipados-16-1-stage-manager-multitasking-basics-how-to-use-the-new-ipad-feature/

Comment: Stage manager allows you to use an external display for placing multitasked app windows.  It **does not** extend your desktop .  You also need an iPad with the M processor so only high horsepower iPads.  Even the last gen iPad Pro can’t use it.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant. I want to replace my laptop with my iPad by plugging it into a 4K screen using the entirety of the monitor display and be able to move applications between the iPad screen and monitor. I think you are saying I need to upgrade my iPad Pro to the latest version to be able to do this - is that correct?